# nodejs: node-gyp rebuild - Access is denied

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

I am trying to install `nodetime` module to profile my `nodejs` app..

When i `run > npm` install `nodetime`
the files are downloaded. but when `node-gyp` rebuild runs.

I get the following error.

> Command failed: CreateProcessW: Access is denied

The same thing happens, when i try to download `v8-profiler`.

> Nodejs ver: 0.8.15
>
> node-gyp: 0.7.1

I have tried this on both my dev machine that runs window 7 and on windows server 2008 where this app will be hosted..

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if more explanation is required

**Update:**

Sorry I had ignored this post for a while.. Had a chat with someone I assume is the author of nodetime and here are the things required for nodetime to run on Windows.

- Python version 2.7
- If on windows the PATH environment variable for python should include python.exe  Eg: C:\Python27\Python.exe
- It requires CPP compilers that come with Visual C++ Express edition and Windows 7 64-bit SDK (SDK compiler is required for 64-bit version of nodejs).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I got the dame error:

configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: CreateProcessW: Access is denied.
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.exithandler(child_process.js:540:15)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:99:17)
gyp ERR! stack at maybeClose (child_process.js:638:16)
gyp ERR! stack at Socket.ChildProcess.spawn.stdin (child_process.js:815:11)
gyp ERR! stack at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
gyp ERR! stack at Socket._destroy.destroyed (net.js:358:10)
gyp ERR! stack at process.startup.processNextTick.process_tickCallback (node.js:244:9)

Answer (score 3):

Try just `set PATH=C:\Python27;%PATH%`

**DO NOT** set PYTHON variable (check that its not set on your machine).

I had incorrectly set the PYTHON variable some time ago - which then caused me this headache for ages until I managed to figure out what was wrong.